# How can I learn which branch is the latest branch in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, branch, checkout

I would like to checkout from the latest branch in mercurial, but I don't know which one it is. How do I list all the branches of a project in Mercurial, and how do I checkout from the latest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag `tip` is always assigned to the most recent changeset; `hg update -r tip` will update to this changeset regardless of which branch you were working in before.

`hg tip` will show information about the tip, including the branch name.

Answer (score 2):

Wooble has answered the 2nd part of your question.
As for the first part...

> How do I list all the branches of a project in Mercurial

Assuming you mean *named branches*, then `hg branches`

If you mean *heads* then `hg heads`

Each of those commands has various options about seeing closed branches, etc.